# What does it mean when I hear giant gates and chains while mining?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was just doing some strip mining and I heard what sounded like a giant gate being closed and some chains moving.

I thought nothing of it until I heard it a second time.

What could be making that sound?

Comment: If you enable captions in the accessibility menu, the game will give names to every single sound that you hear, which may help you figure out what you are listening to.

Comment: I believe this used to indicate the presence of a dark area nearby (like an unexplored cave) but I can't find anything to confirm that now, and as of the Nether update last March I don't believe it's true anymore, [judging by the patch notes](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Java_Edition_20w12a#Gameplay_2).

Comment: @Ajedi32 yeah, you can find the old criteria in [this revision of the ambience wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Ambience?oldid=1491978). "Cave ambience may occur when the player is in the vicinity of an air block with a light level lower than 9, without lighting from the sky. In addition, it can be played in the void. The air block that actually plays the sound does not have to be sealed off from the player." [Ian's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/380963/63088) summarizes the current logic well.

Answer (score 22):

**Nothing.**

What you're hearing are ambient noises, these are noises that Minecraft randomly plays sometimes. They are made to be creepy, but don't actually do anything other than sound weird. A quick search reveals [this](https://youtu.be/IiJZkpEuecc?t=120) which meets your description quite perfectly, I think.

Comment: I have theory that this sound is minecart

Comment: @RayWu are you absolutely sure its not [this ambient sound right here that i can pull up in 2 minutes?](https://youtu.be/IiJZkpEuecc?t=120) because it seems like it is.

Comment: Eh sounds like both I have seen it once a minecart

Comment: Never mind you are right bugs MC-37557 and MC-91163 were fixed in 1.16

Answer (score 7):

**Those sounds are 'cave ambience', and hearing them means you should be careful; you're in the dark, and monsters might be able to spawn.** No 'thing' in particular is making the sound; Minecraft is actually giving you a helpful warning.

**Cave ambience is not random**. It does not indicate that any other event has occurred, but it does provide information about your current location. Minecraft plays ambient cave sounds play when a `mood` value reaches 100%, and then the `mood` resets to 0 and begins to increase again. The rate at which the `mood` value increases is based on an algorithm which considers various factors including depth and darkness, according to [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ambience). I haven't reviewed the code myself, but my personal experience supports this claim.

Since branch mining is typically done deep underground, cave ambience sounds tend to play very shortly after you enter a 'dark' area. Thus, they can serve as a quick warning when you've forgotten to light up a branch mining path sufficiently.

So, I always take cave ambience sounds as a reminder to be cautious, but if I unexpectedly hear them while I'm in my own mine, I know I have a lighting problem, which I'd better fix soon if I want to avoid unwelcome guests.

Answer (score -5):

It indicates a change in the time of day, like day to night and vice versa.
Source? I've played a lot in Survival mode and that really freaked me out when it came out a few updates ago (I think aquatic).
I believe that they added it to help when you are down in the underground to know that time has changed aboveground.

Comment: this is just wrong....

Comment: This is incorrect. Internally, Minecraft stores a `mood` variable for the player that gradually increases depending on the current light level, altitude, and other factors. When `mood` reaches 100%, it plays a random "cave ambiance" (scary) sound and resets to 0 to begin counting up again.